# How to make my iOS application to dynamic

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm new to iPhone development,currently i have to develop my application as dynamic one,Where i have to change the Theme ,App icon,color scheme of application.
with out touching my source code & build file is it possible to do this.

My team lead says it was there in .Net & Java side.like that there in iOS development.

If possible please some one help me solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to apply a theme to an iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730926/best-way-to-apply-a-theme-to-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is posible, but you can't change the appicon and loading screen.
The rest of the theming you will have to code your self.

Comment: u mean using the webservice call ?do u have any logic or sample for that??

Comment: No, you will have to build that all your self.

Comment: after launching the application we cant able to change the app icon??

Comment: No, the app icon is stored in the App Bundle wich is readonly, this also applies for the loading screen (default.png)

Comment: really thanks fpr your kind help yar b in touch :)